# Convert two's complement, left justified integer into regular binary

Tags: binary, type-conversion, raspberry-pi3

I am programming a Raspberry Pi 3 in C++ and Qt. I am using the [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) library to interface with an I2C accelerometer (which I am using to compare tilt angle values but not measure the angle degrees).

I need to determine if one accelerometer reading is greater or less than a previous one or with an arbitrary preset value. (I have an arm on a machine that I want to set to an arbitrary angle and then have the arm move to and from that angle.)

The accelerometer outputs readings in two bytes of twos compliment data. The data is twelve bits left justified. (I assume that means the 4 most significant bits of the accelerometer value are on the left side of the upper byte?) The accelerometer is the LIS3DH.

I am reading the two bytes into my program as 2 integer values but I am struggling in converting the data into useful information.

The wiringPi I2C library only returns integers.

I may need to convert the decimal readings into binary, convert the two bytes of twos compliment left justified binary data into twelve bits of right justified regular binary data.

I am looking for suggestions as to how I might accomplish this and if there are easier ways to do this than the path I listed above.

EDIT:

```
void main(void)       
{
    int acc_l = 0, acc_h = 0;
    acc_l = read_output_register_lo;
    acc_h = read_output_register_hi;

/*
How do I convert acc_l and acc_h to binary?

Do I need to shift acc_h 4 bits to the right?

How do I concatenate acc_h and acc_l into a 12 bit binary number?

How do I convert 12 bit twos compliment binary into regular binary?

Is this the correct process to follow?

Is there an easier way to do this?
*/
}
```

EDIT:
Thank you Roman very much. I had come up with the same basic concept but it appears that I had the two registers reversed. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you have some code that you could post?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using LIS3DH as well, and after a few hours of reading and trying, I've finally figured it out. Though my code is for AVR microcontroller, the method is still the same.

The accelerometer presents its readings as a *left-justified* 16-bit values, divided to 2-byte registers for each axis: `OUT_X_L`, `OUT_X_H`, `OUT_Y_L`, `OUT_Y_H`, `OUT_Z_L`, `OUT_Z_H`. Left justification means: *all value bits are shifted to the left*. How many bits? That depends on your precision.

Suppose you use a 10-bit precision (the default), and you want to read X-axis value, then your `OUT_X_H` and `OUT_X_L` registers will look like this:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║         ║  OUT_X_H  ║  OUT_X_L  ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ Content ║ xxxx xxxx ║ xx00 0000 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

x - is the value you want, and 0 is just a zero. Since the precision is 10-bit, the 6 less significant bits will always be zero-ed.

Why the heck someone would want to send data like that? The reason is simple - if you don't care about a precision, you can read only the high register and store it as an 8-bit integer (`int8_t`). Thanks to the left-justification, more most significant bits are preserved and you lose only 2 bits from the low register. On the other hand, right-justification is easier to operate on, but you lose a lot of information if you don't read a whole 16-bit value.

Now, if you want to convert this value to a "normal" one (right-justified), you need to store it as a 16-bit integer (`int16_t`). Computers hold signed integers as two's complement, so does LIS3DH, that means the value stored in this `int16_t` variable will have a proper sign. The last operation you have to do, is to shift this value right by 6 (for 10-bit precision), and *voila*!

I've written two methods of conversion, one is based on a typical bit operations and the second is a pointer-casting suicide.

#### Bit operations

```
int16_t x = out_x_h; // 1.
x <<= 8;             // 1.
x |= out_x_l;        // 2.
x >>= 6;             // 3.

int16_t y = out_y_h;
y <<= 8;
y |= out_y_l;
y >>= 6;

int16_t z = out_z_h;
z <<= 8;
z |= out_z_l;
z >>= 6;
```

For each axis:

1. Store a high register in the upper part of the 16-bit variable.
2. Append a lower register. Now your variable contains a left-justified value.
3. Shift whole variable by 6 to the right.

#### Pointer-casting suicide

```
uint8_t x_a[2] = {out_x_l, out_x_h}; // 1.
int16_t x = (*(int16_t*) x_a) >> 6;  // 2.

uint8_t y_a[2] = {out_y_l, out_y_h};
int16_t y = (*(int16_t*) y_a) >> 6;

uint8_t z_a[2] = {out_z_l, out_z_h};
int16_t z = (*(int16_t*) z_a) >> 6;
```

For each axis:

1. Store registers in an array of bytes. **Order of elements is valid only for little-endian architecture. For big-endian the high register should be first.**
2. Cast `uint8_t` pointer to `int16_t` pointer, so the pointer to the byte array is seen as a pointer to the one 16-bit integer, dereference it, and shift right by 6.

Comment: Right-shift of signed integer is implementation-defined.  Make sure your compiler does "arithmetic right shift" for this solution to work with negative numbers.

Comment: Need to pick that up: It is indeed implementation defined, how would one do that in a portable way? The problem is you first need to cast to int and then remove the LSB zeros and the sign bits must remain existent

Answer (score 0):

According to the description on LIS3DH (ADC have 10-bit), you should do the following:

```
unsigned int result = ((acc_h & 0x03)<<8) + (acc_l & 0xFF);
```

for 12-bit you need next code:

```
unsigned int result = ((acc_h & 0x0F)<<8) + (acc_l & 0xFF);
```